# Encrypt files in do spaces in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, file, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, laravel-livewire

I have a system that requires upload files in laravel. Now I am required to encrypt some specific files. I have tried in many ways. But nothing works fro me. May anyone suggests me how can I encrypt files in do spaces and decrypt while displaying in blade?

Answer (score 0):

You can `encrypt` and `decrypt` any file in same way you do that with text, [read this article](https://geisi.dev/blog/how-improve-privacy-with-encrypt-files-with-laravel/), here sample of code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): void
    {
        $request->validate(['picture' => ['required', 'file', 'image']]);
        $content = $request->file('picture')->getContent();
        $contentType = $request->file('picture')->getMimeType();
        Storage::disk('spaces')->put('sensitive_user_image.jpg', Crypt::encrypt($content), ['ContentType' => $contentType]);
    }

    public function preview(): Response|Application|ResponseFactory
    {
        $content = Crypt::decrypt(Storage::disk('spaces')->get('sensitive_user_image.jpg'));
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="sensitive_user_image.jpg"',
        ];
        return response($content, 200, $headers);
    }

    public function download(): StreamedResponse
    {
        return response()->streamDownload(function () {
            echo Crypt::decrypt(Storage::disk('spaces')->get('sensitive_user_image.jpg'));
        }, 'sensitive_user_image.jpg');
    }
}
```

You will need to configure the disk in your `config/filesystems.php` file, like so:

```
'spaces' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
    'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
    'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
],
```

Comment: I need to specify the disk to upload in digitalOcean spaces. How can I specify the disk?

Comment: I updated the answer. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: the code is fine for me. The only issue I am facing is I want to display the image or pdf in the browser. I don't want to download. Is it possible to display it in the browser instead of downloading?

Comment: Certainly! It is indeed possible to display an image or PDF in the browser instead of prompting the user to download it. I have updated my previous answer to include the steps to achieve this. If this solution works for you, please consider voting and accepting the answer. Feel free to ask any additional questions if you have any.